# Framework errors: ".objc_class_name_XXX", referenced from

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I have taken over a Cocoa project that includes some frameworks, and I can get no help from the previous developer. When building one of the frameworks, I get 8 errors like this:

> ".objc_class_name_XXX", referenced from

I have tried googling the problem, but I cant get my head around it. Any ideas?

I also get some warnings saying "missing required architecture ppc in file" for a linked framework, could this hint at the problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing `.objc_class_name_XXX` means you’re sending class messages to XXX, but not linking to the binary where XXX’s main implementation is. Presumably this is the framework that doesn’t have a PPC part.

There are three possible ways to fix this:

- Get a version of the framework with a PowerPC part.
- Stop building for PowerPC (the ARCHS build setting).
- Stop using those classes in the PowerPC build of the project (either look them up dynamically using `NSClassFromString` or `#ifdef` them out).

Comment: Pretty spot on. I suspect it's a system framework from 10.6 or newer and he's using the default build settings (which target i386 and PPC32.)

Comment: I removed the ppc parts from my "Valid Architectures" and that removed the errors. Now I have a build framework (Framework_A), and I have copied the Framework_A.framework into the /Library/Frameworks folder and removed any reference to Framework_A from another framework (Framework_B) that uses Framework_A and then added Framework_A to Framework_B again by doubleclicking the target and adding the framework under the general tab. But something is wrong. The header files in Framework_A can not be found from Framework_B and if I try to fold open Framework_A from Framework_B it is empty. What next?